# A migration to add unique constraint to a combination of columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

What I need is a migration to apply unique constraint to a combination of columns. i.e. for a `people` table, a combination of `first_name`, `last_Name` and `Dob` should be unique.

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone reading this question: Don't make a constraint based on first name, last name, and date of birth, because more than one person can match on all three of those. (This is mentioned in an answer, but it isn't really an answer.)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

`add_index :people, [:firstname, :lastname, :dob], unique: true`

Comment: I think that's adding a unique index, *not* a constraint. Or does the index add the constraint as well?

Comment: Nope, it's all good. My bad! The unique constraint comes with the unique index.

Comment: I agree with @paul-cantrell : ain't there any way to only add a constraint, not an index (which has db storage influences)

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger, little reason to put constraint in DB then. Instead, use a validation on the model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/rails-validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns

Comment: The problem with the model level validation is that it doesn't scale.  Two servers could run the same data through at the same time (like a double tap on an api heavy app)  I have two identical records in my DB right now and the model has the validation..

Comment: I like to have both.. Just to make sure

Comment: @baash05 I'm here because of this exactly problem, two servers running the same data at the same time, requested by my API. The model validation is useless in this case

Comment: For lots of discussion about why you need the database to enforce this, not just the model, see http://www.bailis.org/papers/feral-sigmod2015.pdf

Comment: @PaulCantrell I got confused by your comments; the first comment is about whether an index creates a constraint as well, whereas the second comment asserts that a constraint creates an index as well ... while the latter statement is true (for postgres), the converse isn't and requires a different approach, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704445/1338292)

Comment: No, both comments were about whether a unique index automatically creates a unique constraint. I was indeed only considering Postgres.

Comment: Would be helpful to instruct whether or not this operation is compatible with migration "change".

Answer (score 29):

According to howmanyofme.com, "There are 46,427 people named John Smith" in the United States alone. That's about 127 years of days. As this is well over the average lifespan of a human being, this means that a DOB clash is mathematically certain.

All I'm saying is that that particular combination of unique fields could lead to extreme user/customer frustration in future.

Consider something that's actually unique, like a national identification number, if appropriate.

(I realise I'm very late to the party with this one, but it could help future readers.)

Comment: hrm... you are certainly right. but probably it was just an example of what Ian wanted to do just to make the question clear.

Comment: Maybe. The answer wasn't intended for Ian though. Or indeed Rangalo.

Comment: It was intended for all foo-s, not just Ian or rangalo.

Answer (score 28):

You may want to add a constraint without an index.  This will depend on what database you're using.  Below is sample migration code for Postgres.  `(tracking_number, carrier)` is a list of the columns you want to use for the constraint.

```
class AddUniqeConstraintToShipments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      alter table shipments
        add constraint shipment_tracking_number unique (tracking_number, carrier);
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      alter table shipments
        drop constraint if exists shipment_tracking_number;
    SQL
  end
end
```

There are different constraints you can add.  [Read the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-alter.html#AEN2303)

Comment: [Docs for PostgreSQL 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) say: _Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique btree index on the column or group of columns used in the constraint. A uniqueness constraint on only some rows can be enforced by creating a partial index._

So IMHO there's no need to drop to raw SQL when the outcome will be basically the same as using the `add_index` method. ;)

Comment: Actually there is one reason: It is an implementation detail and discouraged by the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-unique.html). Also note that you cannot refer to the constraint by name, since it is not added to the `pg_constraint` table.

Answer (score 20):

For completeness sake, and to avoid confusion here are 3 ways of doing the same thing:
**Adding a named unique constraint to a combination of columns in Rails 5.2+**

Let's say we have Locations table that belongs to an advertiser and has column reference_code and you only want 1 reference code per advertiser. so you want to add a unique constraint to a combination of columns and name it.

Do:

`rails g migration AddUniquenessConstraintToLocations`

And make your migration look either something like this one liner:

```
class AddUniquenessConstraintToLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_index :locations, [:reference_code, :advertiser_id], unique: true, name: 'uniq_reference_code_per_advertiser'
  end
end
```

OR this block version.

```
class AddUniquenessConstraintToLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :locations do |t|
     t.index ['reference_code', 'advertiser_id'], name: 'uniq_reference_code_per_advertiser', unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

OR this raw SQL version

```
class AddUniquenessConstraintToLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
      execute <<-SQL
          ALTER TABLE locations
            ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_reference_code_per_advertiser UNIQUE (reference_code, advertiser_id);
        SQL
  end
end
```

Any of these will have the same result, check your `schema.rb`

Answer (score 11):

Hi You may add unique index in your migration to the columns for example

```
add_index(:accounts, [:branch_id, :party_id], :unique => true)
```

or separate unique indexes for each column

Comment: Sorry, it worked, first I tried by editing and existing migration which didn't work, then added a new one and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In the typical example of a join table between users and posts:

```
create_table :users
create_table :posts

create_table :ownerships do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.belongs_to :post, foreign_key: true, null: false
end

add_index :ownerships, [:user_id, :post_id], unique: true
```

Trying to create two similar records will throw a database error (Postgres in my case):

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_ownerships_on_user_id_and_post_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, post_id)=(1, 1) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "ownerships" ("user_id", "post_id") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"
```

e.g. doing that:

```
Ownership.create!(user_id: user_id, post_id: post_id)
Ownership.create!(user_id: user_id, post_id: post_id)
```

Fully runnable example: https://gist.github.com/Dorian/9d641ca78dad8eb64736173614d97ced

`db/schema.rb` generated: https://gist.github.com/Dorian/a8449287fa62b88463f48da986c1744a

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new table just add unique: true

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title, unique: true
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :posts, :user_id, unique: true
  end
end
```