# How do I validate a unique `social_media_account.type` per `user` in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have many users, and they `has_many :social_media_accounts`, however, I want to only allow a unique `social_media_account.type` per user,

e.g. `User` "Bob" can only have one `social_media_account.type` of "Twitter"

How do I do this?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :social_media_accounts
end

class SocialMediaAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  enum type: [
    twitter:   1,
    facebook: 2,
    linkedin: 3
  ]
end
```

Comment: add custom validation to user and check it here. or add unique constraint

Comment: @AndreyS you'll have to elaborate a little.

Comment: DB way: you can add unique constraint for `user_id` and `social_media_account_id` so you will be assured there's only one record of `social_media_account` for one `user`.App way: you can add custom validates method, which will check existence of social_media_account on creation/modification of user as you need\

Comment: @AndreyS we can validate a combined uniqueness of two attributes? I didn't know that! Please post that in the answer with a reference and i'll accept it!

Comment: @AndreyS: were you talking about scope: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: sure, you can do it with validate uniqueness with scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it two ways:

1. On DB side: create migration for unique index for your `user_id` and `social_media_account_id`. 
   Example is here: [A migration to add unique constraint to a combination of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370271/a-migration-to-add-unique-constraint-to-a-combination-of-columns)
2. On the app side: create validation preventing of creating more than one `social_media_account` for one `user` (Example: `validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :year}`). More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html