# how to create migration to add unique constrain scope by some columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

How do I add database constrain for following statement written in rails model

> validates :column_1, uniqueness: { scope: [:column_2, :column_3] }

Thank in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29961501/4481312

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate uniqueness of multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A migration to add unique constraint to a combination of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370271/a-migration-to-add-unique-constraint-to-a-combination-of-columns)

Answer (score 3):

Run the following migration:

```
def change    
  add_index :table_name, [:column_1, :column_2,:column_3], unique: true
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Othmane El Kesri ! adding above restrict to add same combinition for column_2 and column_3 but in my case, I want combinition with column_1 too. So adding `add_index :table_name, [column_1,:column_2,:column_3], unique: true`. Is that correct way?

Comment: i updated my answer, please check it if it's the correct one